# Split string by ' and -

Tags: python

How do split string by apostrophe `'` and `-` ?

For example, given

```
string = "pete - he's a boy"
```

Comment: `[item.split("'") for item in string.split('-')]` Is what I came up with, not really an answer though...

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: this work : re.split('\W+',string)

Comment: using `'\W+'` works here, but in general it's wrong. And note that `r'\W+'` is more robust, see [documentation about string literals](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

Comment: @JakobBowyer: The result of your suggestion yields a list of lists, which (I think) isn't the intention here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the regular expression module's [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) function:

```
re.split("['-]", "pete - he's a boy")
```

Comment: that doesn´t work you need to escape the characters like one answer below =P

Comment: @fceruti You only need to escape the single-quote if you're using a single-quoted string, but this string is double-quoted. The hyphen doesn't need to be escaped at all.

Answer (score 9):

```
string = "pete - he's a boy"
result = string.replace("'", "-").split("-")
print result

['pete ', ' he', 's a boy']
```

Comment: Thats a cute way of working it out.

Comment: Anything to avoid using regular expressions ;D

Comment: works fine. I guess it depends on the size of the string to split if this one is faster or the re.split approach.

Comment: They can be useful. In moderation.

Comment: Clean and efficient !!!

Answer (score 2):

This feels kind of hacky but you could do:

```
string.replace("-", "'").split("'")
```

Comment: equivalent to [slightly earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894392/python-split-string-by-and/5894465#5894465)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without regular expressions. Use the split method on string ( and using list comprehensions - effectively the same as [@Cédric Julien's earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5894465/151019)

First split once on one splitter e.g. '-' then split each element of the array

```
l = [x.split("'") for x in "pete - he's a boy".split('-')]
```

Then flattern the lists

```
print ( [item for m in l for item in m ] )
```

giving

```
['pete ', ' he', 's a boy']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "pete - he's a boy"
>>> re.split('[\'\-]', string)
['pete ', ' he', 's a boy']
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It might be an idea to check for other peoples answers first. @Uwe has already provided a suitable re expression.

Comment: Im sorry, when I wrote it, it said no one has posted yet. But anyway, their is an error in his answer.

Comment: Note I used double quotes for the pattern argument, so there is no need to quote.

Comment: Oh, thanks, now I´ve learned one thing :) (double quotes)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
string = "pete - he's a boy"
print re.findall("[^'-]+",string)
```

result

```
['pete ', ' he', 's a boy']
```

.

and if you want no blank before nor after each item after spliting:

```
import re
string = "pete - he's a boy"
print re.findall("[^'-]+",string)
print re.findall("(?! )[^'-]+(?<! )",string)
```

result

```
['pete', 'he', 's a boy']
```